# Install SASS with Homebrew?

Tags: sass, homebrew

Is there a way to install sass with homebrew? I tried `brew install sass` which brought up some errors. I understand I can `gem install sass` but for better organization and management, is there a way to use homebrew?

If not, is there some reason it isn't possible or necessary?

Comment: For the record, `gem install sass` has been deprecated.

Answer (score 6):

```
brew install --devel sass/sass/sass
```

And you are good to go.

`--devel` stands for development version so you are always on the bleeding edge.